# How to put multiple singletons in one qmldir file?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I want to use multiple singletons in one qmldir file but it doesn't seem to work, I don't have an error but the program doesn't launch.

qmldir:

```
singleton File1 1.0 File.qml
singleton File2 1.0 File2.qml
```

main:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qstr("hello world!")

    Button {    
        onCliked: File2.test();
    }
}
```

File2.qml:

```
pragma Singleton
import QtQuick 2.7
Item {
    signal test;
    onTest: console.log("File2 received signal");
}
```

File1.qml:

```
pragma Singleton
import QtQuick 2.7
Item {
    signal test;
    onTest: console.log("File1 received signal");
}
```

The code works if I delete the second line in qmldir, but then File2 will be undefined.

Comment: _Multiple Singletons_ is a bit contradictorily, no?

Comment: yes indeed , but when i looked for a way to sort of link qml files to be able to send and receive signals from one another as shown in the example above , singleton seemed to be the only solution , with no knowledge of what singleton meant i figured that it would be great if i could apply it to multiple files to link them , if i can't do that ,so please tell me what can i do ?

Comment: Multiple different singletons are not contradictory.

Comment: so @AlexanderVX what should i do ?

Comment: How to tell why it does not launch? Debug log?

Comment: Please expand your example, so that the code posted can reproduce the *non-startup*. Sometimes QML is somewhat silent about problems some problems. Per se, as shown above is, how you create multiple singletons.

Comment: Debug log doesnt show anything , it's like there is no problem.

Comment: @user0042 - you imply that you can only have one singleton in your application? You can't like... have say 2 different singleton types?

Comment: just what iam trying to do , use two files eachone as a singleton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `qmldir` file is exactly as you have written:

```
Singleton File1 1.0 File.qml
Singleton File2 1.0 File2.qml
```

The error might reside within that, as the keyword is `singleton`, not `Singleton`.

Try that:

```
singleton File1 1.0 File.qml
singleton File2 1.0 File2.qml
```

But that error should not fail silently. There should be some errors:

> [main.qml] a component declaration requires two or three arguments, but 4 were provided
> [qmldir] a component declaration requires two or three arguments, but 4 were provided

*main.qml:*

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import '.'

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window    
    width: 800
    height: 600
    visible: true    
    Row {
        spacing: 3
        Button {
            text: 'single1'
            onClicked: Single.sig()
        }

        Button {
            text: 'signle2'
            onClicked: Single2.sig()
        }
    }    
}
```

*singleton.qml*

```
pragma Singleton
import QtQuick 2.0
QtObject {
    signal sig
    onSig: console.log('Singleton1 Received')
}
```

*singleton2.qml*

```
pragma Singleton
import QtQuick 2.0
QtObject {
    signal sig
    onSig: console.log('Singelton2 Received')
}
```

*qmldir*

```
singleton Single 1.0 singleton.qml
singleton Single2 1.0 singleton2.qml
```

---

Works like a charm.